# VBA's range causes "Run time error 9 Subscript out of range"

Tags: excel, vba

The following code fails whenever I go beyond certain number of columns e.g. if I was using this array: AD2:BM, everything works well and it bounds the letter with each other (its original purpose). However, whenever I try to go from AD2:KQ it fails by indicating

> Run time error 9 Subscript out of range.

Can you please advise how to extend the ranges within this code (without generating error)? Regards West

```
Sub WL()
  Dim R As Long, C As Long, X As Long, Data As Variant
  Data = Range("AD2:BM" & Columns("AD:BM").Find("*", , xlValues, , xlRows, xlPrevious).Row)
  For R = 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
    X = -1
    For C = 1 To UBound(Data, 2)
      If Len(Data(R, C)) Then
        X = X + 1
        If X Then Data(R, C) = Data(R, C + 1) & Data(R, C)
      End If
    Next
  Next
  Range("AD2:BM2").Resize(UBound(Data)) = Data
End Sub
```

**2. UPDATE:**

All strings of W's & L's begin with one letter and end with one letter. 
Everything inbetween is perfect.

The question is: what can be done to double first far-right and first far-left values (that are singles)? E.g. I have highlighted these event on the attached photo below [don't be fooled, every single string starts and ends with one letter - these two cases are simply visible in their entirety].

I need beginning and ending L or W to double, from W to WW and from L to LL. Wherease the W's & L's in between to remain the way they are, i.e. move from one period to the other and join other single letter [just like in the code below].

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are incrementing C to the UBound(Data, 2) but within that loop you expect to use Data(r, C + 1) which is outside the UBound.

```
Sub WL()
  Dim R As Long, C As Long, X As Long, Data As Variant
  Data = Range("AD2:BM" & Columns("AD:BM").Find("*", , xlValues, , xlRows, xlPrevious).Row)
  For R = 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
    X = -1
    For C = 1 To UBound(Data, 2) - 1   '<~~ FIX HERE!!
      If Len(Data(R, C)) Then
        X = X + 1
        If X Then Data(R, C) = Data(R, C + 1) & Data(R, C)    'Now C+1 doesn't error
      End If
    Next
  Next
  Range("AD2:BM2").Resize(UBound(Data)) = Data
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! You are awesome Jeeped !

Comment: Jeeped, interestingly I need your advice again. Please see update to the question (2.).